# Setting variable in bash using an awscli command returns command not found

Tags: bash, aws-cli

When I try to set a variable in a bash script using AWSCLI it errors with the command not found

```
ACC_ID=$(aws sts get-caller-identity --output text --query 'Account')

aws: command not found
```

This is on Ubuntu 18 and using `#!/bin/bash -x`

Comment: what is the output of `which aws` ?

Comment: `/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/aws`

Comment: And: `file /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/aws` and `ls -l /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/aws` ?

Comment: If I type `someInvalidCommand` in bash I get the error message `bash: someInvalidCommand: command not found` (note the `bash:` at the beginning). Could it be that the error message comes from the `aws` command itself because `sts`, `get-caller-identity` or something like that isn't known? However, with `set -x` I also get a `+ someInvalidCommand …` *before* the error. Maybe the different error message is just because of different bash versions. I am using 5.0.11.

Comment: @GillesQuenot `/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/aws: Python script, ASCII text executable` & `-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 815 Dec 12 17:21 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/aws`

Comment: @Socowi It is 100% an awscli command and runs without the $()

Comment: I see you are using UPPERCASE variable names which easily lead to collisions. Is the code you showed us part of a longer script, and in this script, did you name any variable `PATH` by accident?

Comment: @JoshEdwards use "sudo ln -s /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/aws /usr/local/bin/aws" it should solve your issue.

Comment: Still no luck :( no PATH set and I tried the symlink, that didn't work either